# Where to start designing a ~1Hz to ~60Hz square wave oscillator as a switch for a Klomp dirty video mixer?

Tags: oscillator, video

[image: Klomp mixer diagram]

So I built this circuit and in messing around with it I found if I switched quickly between a camera (feedback) source and a video source in quick succession with the switch I obtained an aesthetically pleasing result. So I want to automate that switching behaviour and control the rate of that oscillator with a potentiometer. I got a 555 chip because I thought that might help, but I have no idea how to actually design a circuit, or if the 555 is even capable of doing what I want.

Comment: Do you make much money from mixing dirty videos?

Comment: What on earth is a "klomp dirty video mixer"?

Comment: It accepts two RCA jack video inputs (V in 1, V in 2) and outputs them to V out. The dirty comes from interference created by two images when panning the potentiometer.

Comment: With two SPDT switches and 2 sources there are only 3 Combo’s. 1,mix or 2  and the a 4th mode if you modulate between 1&2 by some mix amount from 0 to 100% . Is that what you want?  Consider <5 Ohm Analog SPST or SPDT switches and a Schmitt Trigger pot controlled Osc for logic level switch control.

Comment: An easier solution to engineer in the short term just replaces the switches with relays instead of analog switches - but relays have a finite lifetime, and you could probably only expect them to switch up to 10Hz or so.